# WebDriver – Inconsistent Action of Method to Check an Element is Visible

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have a web page that uses a DatePicker control to enter a DoB as one of the criteria for a search. The issue I have had to resolve is that the datepicker hides the button to execute the Search. To get rid of the datepicker I click on another field, and then use a method that should wait until the Search button is visible and click it. My issue is that sometime this works, but more often it does not and I get the *Element is not clickable .. Other element would receive the click* exception. The calling code is below.

```
WebDriverSupport.ClearAndEnterDataIntoFieldById(driver, "txtDateOfBirthNew", "01/01/1980"); // causes the datepicker to appear
WebDriverSupport.ClickElementById(driver, "txtSurnameNew");   // to close date picker click on another field
WebDriverSupport.ClickElementById(driver, "btnSearch"); // wait for the search button to appear and click
```

The ClickElementById method is defined as,

```
/// <summary>
/// WebDriver: Clicks on an element
/// </summary>
/// <param name="driver">WebDriver object</param>
/// <param name="id">Name of element (by ID) to click</param>
/// <returns>None</returns>
public static void ClickElementById(IWebDriver driver, string id)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id(id)));
    element.Click();
}
```

If I run in debug mode and put a breakpoint on the statement that clicks on the Search button, and then continue from there it works every time. But I guess this is because there is time for the datepicker to disappear and the button to become visible.
What I cannot figure out is the ClickElementById method is waiting for the element to be visible before it moves onto doing the click, so why the exception? And why it works some times and not others.

Any advice on resolving this issue? Is there a more robust method for checking an element is visible and can be clicked on?

Answer (score 0):

`ElementIsVisible` checks if at least part of the element is displayed. However, it's not always good enough for the `click()` method. Try using `MoveToElement` from [Actions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Interactions_Actions.htm) class

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id(id)));

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(element).Perform();

element.Click();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. To me it looks like the **ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible** is not a reliable test for an element being visible and active so it can be "clicked" on. Is their a better test that we can use?

Comment: @Cooldudescrib You can try `ElementToBeClickable()`

Comment: `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id(id)));`

Comment: Thanks this appears to work, but it works inconsistently. I run my code and it works. I then run the code in debug mode (no breakpoints) and it does not work - I get the _Element is not clickable .. Other element would receive the click_ exception. It is this inconsistency that I find frustrating when something will work one time and then not another time. With this happening it is hard to put together a reliable set of tests.